# Angular fill ng-options from http request

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise, ng-options

I have a select tag that gets data from selectable variable.

```
<select multiple chosen class="chosen-select"  ng-change="onSelectChange()" ng-model="rowVars" ng-options="v for v in selectable">
```

and a function that make a http request to import selectable variables.

```
function importData(){
    var variables =[];
    return $q(function(resolve,reject){
              //some staff
              resolve(variables);
    })
}
```

then I assign this functions result to a promise.

```
var promise= importData();
promise.then(function(variables){
    $scope.selectable =variables;
});
```

My problem is on angular start select tag works with an empty array then make assign operation to selectable variable so ng-options directive not watching my variable if it change or not

Comment: what data in `$scope.selectable` variable ?

Comment: an array like ["a","b","c","d"], i see it's working if I don't use chosen directive,

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/juqoNOt1z1Gb349XabQ2?p=preview I tried to use this dropdown multiple select again not working. It reads empty array because on page load directive working before http response come

Comment: can your post your code on plnkr to review it